# Winapi : Change Color of a TreeView using CustomDraw

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview, custom-draw

I am currently trying to change the background color of a TreeView item.
Therefore, I am using this message to create the item:

```
    SendMessage(ListView, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvI);
```

Additionally, I am handling the custom draw message like this :

```
        case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            LPNMLISTVIEW pnm = (LPNMLISTVIEW)lParam;
            if (pnm->hdr.code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
            {
                LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
                switch (lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
                {
                    case CDDS_PREPAINT :
                        return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
                    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
                        lplvcd->clrTextBk = ???;

                        return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                }
            }
```

This works fine and I can set the color to whatever I'd like to,
However, I have not found a way to pass the color as a parameter right when I send the message, yet.
After all, custom draw is useless for me when I can only assign a constant or random color.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: I'm not sure, but `NMLISTVIEW::lParam` seems like the custom data you want.

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure how I have to get the information out of the lParam later on : lplvcd->clrTextBk = (COLORREF)lParam; -> is creating random colors

Comment: How about `NMCUSTOMDRAW::lItemlParam`, but, then again, I don't know how to set it.

Comment: NMCUSTOMDRAW::lItemlParam keeps returning 0 :/

Comment: When you add the item to the list, you can pass your own data by setting the `LVIF_PARAM` flag and filling out the `lParam` member of the `LVITEM` structure. This then gets passed back to you as `NMCUSTOMDRAW::lItemlParam`. Don't get confused by the `lParam` that that comes with the `WM_NOTIFY` message itself, that's a different `lParam` :)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Is there any way I can flag your answer as accepted? :)

Comment: Sure, I'll post it as an answer, I just wasn't sure that was actually the question you were asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the item to the list, you can pass your own data by setting the `LVIF_PARAM` flag and filling out the `lParam` member of the `LVITEM` structure. This then gets passed back to you as `NMCUSTOMDRAW::lItemlParam`.

Don't get confused by the `lParam` that that comes with the `WM_NOTIFY` message itself, that's a different `lParam` :)

Comment: How do you use the `NMCUSTOMDRAW::lItemlParam` member ? I mean how do you retrieve the current `NMCUSTOMDRAW` object ?

Comment: **EDIT** All right it's `LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW lpNMCustomDraw = (LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam` and `lpNMCustomDraw->nmcd.lItemlParam` for tree view items.

Answer (score 0):

I think the (exact) answer lies here: [Using Custom Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Well, I was using this article as a template and it explains how to use customdraw but it doesn't show how to pass the argument via SendMessage or am I missing something?